# Webkit GTK: Stop loading and reset web view

Tags: c++, webkit, gtk

I'm trying to write a C++ program using the **[Webkit GTK](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html)** API.  The program simply loads a page, then processes it, then loads another page, and so on.

Sometimes a page takes too long to load, so I have a [timeout callback](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) which is invoked after a certain time.  The callback simply calls [webkit_web_view_stop_loading()](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-stop-loading), and then loads the next page.

The problem is that I can't find any way to RESET the state of the [WebkitWebView](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html) object after a page load is cancelled.  So what happens sometimes is, I'll call [webkit_web_view_load_uri()](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-load-uri) to load Page A.  But then loading Page A takes too long, so the timeout is invoked, and [webkit_web_view_stop_loading()](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-stop-loading) is called.  Then I begin to load Page B, but various resources leftover from Page A (like CSS files, JPEGs, Iframes, whatever) still cause callbacks to be invoked, even though my intention is to completely stop ALL loading of Page A.

What I'm looking for is something like a webkit_web_view_reset() function (which doesn't exist), that will reset the state of the [WebkitWebView](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html) object, so I can begin loading a new page from scratch.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options that you may consider:

- You could create a new web view.
- You could load your own html using `webkit_web_view_load_html_string()`.
- Or you could also go back using `webkit_web_view_go_back_or_forward()` or `webkit_web_view_go_back_or_forward()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to do is terminate all pre-existing sessions (aka connections) associated with that session. The way to do this is to use the WebKit global function (http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-Global-functions.html) `webkit_get_default_session()`. This will return a `SoupSession` instance where you can call the `soup_session_abort()` (https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupSession.html#soup-session-abort) or `soup_session_cancel_message()` (https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupSession.html#soup-session-cancel-message) functions to kill/cancel all pending and idle requests.